# Can i use socket io + javascript instead of template engine nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, template-engine

For data communication between server and front ui node use template engine such as jade, ejs and some others. but i can  send and receive dynamic data using socket.io emit and on.event function. is this the correct method or not what will be the deficiency of replacing template engine with socket.io.

I am really confuse with template engine so in short don't want to use it.

Comment: Hello, You mean should your socket push js template or html directly instead of JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

a template engine such as jade would help you make server rendered views.

ie: based on a certain url, the server would know how to fill out the variables in a jade template, then return that html to the browser.

socket.io could be used to transfer info to the server from the client, and then do the appropriate dom manipulations on the client based on the server's response.

in socket.io's case, the server would respond to the initial request with generic/base html and then manipulate it based on subsequent socket.io interactions.

socket.io/sockets will probably make more sense to you if you look at them as an alternative to the standard api request/response formula, not as a replacement for a templating engine. ie: sockets keep an open channel between your server and the client, where information can pass back and forth instead of making new server request calls every time you need new data.